# In XCode, why are my custom view's children under the custom view?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've added a custom view to a scene in storyboard. I then add new views to the custom view.  These views shop up above the custom view in IB but render under the custom view at runtime.  If I switch the class of the custom view to "UIView" then the new child views render correctly.

Why is this so, and how can I stop the new views from rendering under the custom view?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was because I was adding a child view as a subview to the view which holds the controls.  So, instead of the controls being children of the subview, they were siblings with the subview.  This caused the issue.